# Having two TFS Servers

Tags: tfs, checkin, tfs-workitem

I'd like to know if there is some way to make a checkin on a TFS server associated to a Work Item that's on another.

Currently some of our developers use a TFS that's hosted offshore containing the source code and we need to install another TFS locally to use Work Items as a project management tool and for the rest of our developers.

Beeing able to associate the two (work items + checkins) would be nice but I presume it's not possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/d3ddf813-dc13-48a2-808e-7887ddc4d9b1